# React Hooks - Memoise functions without invoking them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a following function which I use to control my modals:

```
const getModalProps = useCallback(
(id) => ({
  onClose: () => handleClose(id),
  onOpen: () => handleOpen(id),
  isOpen: isOpen(id),
}),
[handleClose, handleOpen, isOpen],
);
```

The idea is to be used something like `<Modal {...getModalProps('userModal')} />`. Problem arrives when I want to use it in the following way:

```
const modalProps = getModalProps('userModal');

useEffect(() => { modalProps.onOpen() }, [modalProps.onOpen])
```

This causes an infinite loop, because `modalProps.onOpen` is actually an anonymous arrow function, instead of useCallback memoised function.

I am at loss of ideas as to how I can use `getModalProps` function which returns memoised, but not invoked functions of `handleOpen` and `handleClose`.

Something like this is the idea (**I am aware this cannot work, just a concept**):

```
const getModalProps = useCallback(
(id) => ({
  onClose: memoise(() => handleClose(id)),
  onOpen: memoise(() => handleOpen(id)),
  isOpen: isOpen(id),
}),
[handleClose, handleOpen, isOpen],
);
```

`handleClose` and `handleOpen` are just your normal `useCallback` functions.

Please leave a comment if more info is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom hook that create memoized `onClose`, and `onOpen`, and returns the `modalProps` object:

```
const useGetModalProps = id => { // you can also pass isOpen to the hook
  const onClose = useCallback(() => handleClose(id), [handleClose, id]);
  const onOpen = useCallback(() => handleOpen(id), [handleOpen, id]);

  return {
    onClose,
    onOpen,
    isOpen: isOpen(id),
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
const modalProps = useGetModalProps('userModal');

useEffect(() => { modalProps.onOpen() }, [modalProps.onOpen])
```

Or

```
<Modal {...modalProps } />
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent too much time trying to make one hook responsible for everything. This led me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard sometimes looking at a problem in a different way, when you are invested in a solution.